# Parse.com get value with query

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I've been looking for an example on how to use Parse.com queries. It's been really vague.
I think it should start with:

```
ParseQuery query=ParseQuery.getQuery(<Class(aka table name)>);
```

But then, i've got no idea. You can do something like

```
query.whereEqualsTo(<collumn>,value)
```

In that case i get the 'value' back if it exists.
What I am trying to do is. I got a table with the collumns ID and Name.
I know what the ID is, it is 0. So now I want to know what Name belongs to the ID = 0..
But what query should I use, I have no idea ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse's Android Guide has a basic query example [here](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries) which will return the first object which matches your constraints:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("YourClassName");
query.whereEqualTo("ID", "someID");
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
      Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
      Log.d("score", "Retrieved the object.");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: if i want  to find list of user whose username starts from abc then how will i do @Hector Ramos

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend using getFirstInBackground for getting a query, it is much better to use findInBackGround and then filtering the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To find the list of user whose username starts with abc,You can use the condition

```
query.whereStartsWith("username", "abc");
```

So the entire query looks as

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("YourClassName");
query.whereStartsWith("username", "abc");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
      Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
      Log.d("score", "Retrieved the object.");
    }
  }
});
```