# Check for username's existence | Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm searching for a good way of querying usernames towards my app's user-database. So that people can't signup with the same username as someone else.

I'm using a username, password and an email for recover of password. So I want to check for username's basically. 
I've understood this can be achieved with ParseQuery?
I would like an example if anyone can provide?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222158/parse-com-get-value-with-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ParseQuery` to query all usernames in the database like this.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
     query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
         public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
             if (e == null) {
                 // objects is a list of all the User you have. Just get all the usernames, 
                //and check if there's already one equal to the one you want to insert.
             } else {
                 //error handling
             }
         }
     }
```