# Trying to populate a ListView with results from a Parse query

Tags: java, android, listview, search, parse-platform

I've got a simple app where users sign up and sign in, and I want them to be able to search for other users.

I'm using parse.com to store my users and their details, and have been looking into a way to search for users (using either names, phone numbers, emails, etc) and show them all in a list view, but i've come up empty. Most answers and tutorials involve using ParseQueryAdapter, but it looks like that class is no longer included in the SDK.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks for your time

EDIT: I've been messing around with ParseQuery, to try and get something. This is what I have so far:

```
 searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                //TODO search function

                query.whereContains("name", searchText.getText().toString().trim());
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d("Brand", "Retrieved " + objects.size() + " Brands");
                            for (ParseObject dealsObject : objects)
                            {
                                Log.i("USERNAME", dealsObject.getString("name"));
                                // use dealsObject.get('columnName') to access the properties of the Deals object.
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("Brand", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        });
```

This code outputs the number of results from the search as well as the "name" attribute for each test results to the log.

Additionally, I've already made a layout for each item in the list view, containing name, email, phone number and such details. Earlier, before I started using Parse, I was using a local MySQL database to store my users. I would then search for the user, which returned a JsonArray, and I would put each attribute into a custom "searchresult" object which had get() and set() methods for search attributes. After that I had an ArrayAdapter which I added the results to. This method was kind of inefficient, especially since I'm not an expert in PHP and Json.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the SDK's [`ParseQuery`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html).  (If so, please indicate that in the question.)  Can you show us how you're using it?  For example, hard code a query that gets results from *your* dataset?  Once we have that, we can show you how to build a `ListView` using the results.

Comment: So far, I don't have a working ParseQuery, as I've been stuck trying to figure out how it works, and how it returns the results. Ideally I think I'd need it to return a list of users that match the search string. I'll update the post with what I have so far

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222158/parse-com-get-value-with-query) and [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.parse.ParseQuery) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsBWDbmYPwg) should get you going.  *When* you get something that returns results, *then* your ListView problem is relevant.  Just make sure you post working code for us to work with.

Comment: I edited the post with some code that's returning results. Although this only searches by "name", whereas ideally it would search in every field. Thanks for the links though, I'll definitely check them out

Comment: have you tried `whereStartsWith`

Comment: WhereContains is working fine for what I want, but only for one field at a time (in this case, I'm using it with "name"). If i could have 

     ... wherecontains("name", searchString) || wherecontains("email", searchString) ...

then I'd be set, but i don't think I can do it this way

Comment: For the record, ParseQueryAdapter has moved to ParseUI library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this. First, the search for any user matching any fields:

```
String searchParams = searchText.getText().toString().trim();

                if(!searchParams.isEmpty()) {
                    final ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
                    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(activityContext, searchResults);
                    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryName = ParseUser.getQuery();
                    queryName.whereContains("name", searchParams);
                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryPhone = ParseUser.getQuery();
                    queryPhone.whereContains("username", searchParams);
                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryEmail = ParseUser.getQuery();
                    queryEmail.whereContains("email", searchParams);
                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> querySurname1 = ParseUser.getQuery();
                    querySurname1.whereContains("surname1", searchParams);
                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> querySurname2 = ParseUser.getQuery();
                    querySurname2.whereContains("surname2", searchParams);

                    List<ParseQuery<ParseUser>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseUser>>();
                    queries.add(queryName);
                    queries.add(queryPhone);
                    queries.add(queryEmail);
                    queries.add(querySurname1);
                    queries.add(querySurname2);

                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);

                    mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null)
                            {
                                Log.d("Brand", "Retrieved " + objects.size() + " Brands");
                                for (ParseObject dealsObject : objects) {
                                    Log.i("USERNAME", dealsObject.getString("name"));
                                    Log.i("PRIVATE", Integer.toString(dealsObject.getInt("private")));
                                    SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
                                    sr1.setName(dealsObject.getString("name"));
                                    sr1.setSurname1(dealsObject.getString("surname1"));
                                    sr1.setSurname2(dealsObject.getString("surname2"));
                                    sr1.setUid(dealsObject.getObjectId());
                                    Log.d("UID",dealsObject.getObjectId());

                                    if(dealsObject.getInt("private") == 0)
                                    {
                                        sr1.setEmail(dealsObject.getString("email"));
                                        sr1.setPhone(dealsObject.getString("username"));
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sr1.setPhone("xxx-xxx-xxx");
                                        sr1.setEmail("xxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx");
                                    }

                                    searchResults.add(sr1);
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.d("Brand", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }

                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And my SearchResults class:

```
public class SearchResults
{
    private String name = "";
    private String surname1 = "";
    private String surname2 = "";
    private String phone = "";
    private String email = "";
    private Bitmap image;
    private String uid = "";

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getSurname1() {
        return surname1;
    }

    public String getSurname2() {
        return surname2;
    }

    public void setSurname1(String surname1) {
        this.surname1 = surname1;
    }

    public void setSurname2(String surname2) {
        this.surname2 = surname2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
query.whereContains("name", searchText.getText().toString().trim());
query.whereContains("phone", searchText.getText().toString().trim());
query.whereContains("emails", searchText.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: Oh sweet, I'll definitely try this, I hadn't thought of it. That would solve one part of my issue, and I think I can implement my previous class to fill out the ListView.

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't seem to be working. I think if I do it this way, it's looking for a match in "name" AND "phone" etc, but I need it to be an OR. It needs to return the user if it finds the search parameter in any of its fields.

Comment: Just figured it out, several different queries need to be created, one per field constraint, then added to a list of queries. After that, another query is created of the type ParseQuery.or() that takes as an argument the list of queries.